# Get list of values from dropdown that are NOT selected using jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two related dropdowns.

When the user selects an option from the first drop down, the second drop down is populated with a list of all the options from the first drop down that were NOT selected.

I'm trying to use jquery to get all the not selected options, but I'm still a jquery newb and must be mising something.

I am trying the following:

```
$('#segmentCrossStreet1:not(:selected)')
```

This is where "segmentCrossStreet1" is the ID of the first drop down.  This doesn't appear to return anything useful.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your dropdown an HTML element or custom-made with JS and the alike? It would be nice if you posted your HTML structure.

Comment: The dropdown is a simple HTML element, not custom made with JS.  I fill it using AJAX and jquery, but other than that, it is static on the page.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzhWS/** (this fiddle also shows how to pupulate another `<select>`)

You have to select the `<option>` elements, rather than the "selected `<select>`" elements:

```
$('#segmentCrossStreet1 option:not(:selected)');
```

Comment: This is definitely an improvement, but still gets me all the options from the list?

Comment: @AmandaMyer Click at the Fiddle, and have a careful look at the numbers. When you select "Test 2", you won't be able to find `Test 2` at the second `<select>`.

Comment: Ah sorry.. my mistake.  I see now what it is doing.  Thanks for the example. =)

Comment: Note that `.clone()` is used before `.appendTo`. If you omit `clone`, the options disappear from the original `<select>`.

Answer (score 9):

Your current selector:

```
$('#segmentCrossStreet1:not(:selected)')
```

Searches for all `#segmentCrossStreet1` elements that are not selected. Is this what you want? I doubt it. Add a space before `:not(` to search for *child* elements:

```
$('#segmentCrossStreet1: not(:selected)')
```

Better if you made it more specific:

```
$('#segmentCrossStreet1: option:not(:selected)')
```

Comment: Wish I could pick two answers!  Went with Rob W because his was first, but yours works just as well.  Thanks. =)

Comment: Don't think I cry in a corner because my answer didn't get accepted ;)