# jQuery snippet not working

Tags: jquery, jinja2

I don't know much about jQuery, but I found [a useful snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967629/get-list-of-values-from-dropdown-that-are-not-selected-using-jquery) that I wanted to incorporate in my code.

I have tried the following:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Kies je activiteiten</legend>
        <select id="tenemen" class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" multiple>
            {% for activiteit in activiteiten %} 
            <option value="{{activiteit.id}}" selected>{{activiteit.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <select id="telaten" class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" multiple>
        </select>
    </fieldset> 
</form>
<script>
$('#tenemen').change(function(){
$('#telaten').html(''); //Clear
$('#tenemen option:not(:selected)')
.clone()
.appendTo('#telaten')
})
</script>
```

The {%%} tags are Jinja's, but that shouldn't matter.

I have tried it in [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mz586/), and it works, so I don't understand why it doesn't work in my template. jQuery is loaded in the base template as follows: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>`

I am really not familiar with jQuery, so it may be something very stupid. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ok, there is some code and it does what it's told to do, but what was it intended to do? Thats the question... you should write that

Comment: Just what the original snippet was supposed to do; create a new select with the elements that were not selected in the original select.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to wait until the document is ready...

```
$(function(){
   $('#tenemen').change(function(){
     $('#telaten').html(''); //Clear
     $('#tenemen option:not(:selected)')
     .clone()
     .appendTo('#telaten')
   })
})
```

the reason why it is working in jsfiddle is that jsfiddle fires your code "onload" automatically. when you embed the code in a real html-file you need to tell the browser that it has to wait untill the document is loaded before executing the code.

Comment: Waiting doesn't make a difference. The document is ready, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: the code above should work exactly the same as in the jsfiddle. If it doesn't you have some errors elsewhere... My guess is your templating engine. try to run your code local without templating engine... also check your js console for errors.

Comment: In the console, I get [00:18:43.988] `ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ http://127.0.0.1:5000/activiteiten:83` and `[00:18:44.088] ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined @ http://127.0.0.1:5000/activiteiten:668`It's only when I run it with the template that it does not work (i.e. it does work when running it locally without Jinja)

Comment: did you included script tags for jquery and modernizr in your html? if so, are you sure they are loaded before other script tags with a jquery/modernizr dependency.